# UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: causes app to freeze

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

The setup I have on the iPad is a UISplitViewController that handles the main content of the app. This is set to the rootViewController of the UIWindow.

When the app launches, I test to see if the user is able to login to the web service. If the user isn't able to access the web service they are presented with a UIViewController subclass which handles the authentication for the user. The UIViewController subclass is presented modally by calling:

`[splitViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

When the user successfully logs in, the loginViewController is dismissed by calling:

`[splitViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Using reveal app (http://revealapp.com) I'm able to see that the splitViewController is now being presented modally rather than as expected.

As a result of the splitViewController being presented modally, it now doesn't accept any input from the user.

Has anyone come across this scenario before and is able to help me out.

UPDATE:

The problem looks like it is to do with a UIAlertView that gets presented when the login is being attempted. This appears between when the user taps on "Login" and the login is verified. Does anyone know why / how this would be causing a problem? Either the UIAlertView isn't being dismissed properly or the LoginViewController isn't.

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: Make sure that you are dismissing the view controller on the main thread.  Especially since you are responding to an authentication request, if you are doing it from a callback method you may not be and it can cause all kinds of strange problems....

Comment: Same behaviour when placing it in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_thread(), ^{}); block.

Comment: The view is dismissed, though the control is not returned to the splitViewController.

Comment: Oh, and although I didn't mention it in the first comment, make sure that you are presenting the VC on the main thread as well....

Comment: Ahh well, sorry that didn't help!

Comment: That's okay mate. They are good suggestions, just not quite there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32379/discussion-between-matt-delves-and-lnafziger)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted was:

```
[loginViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[splitViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: From the apple documents about UIViewController and dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: -- The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.