# dismissViewControllerAnimated freeze the App

Tags: uitableview, swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I've a `tableView` which appear modally from another controller, in this table user select a row then, clicking the row, tableView closes and user get back to previous controller with `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in UITableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Strange thing is that, after user's tap, `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` locks app for some seconds or until user click the screen for a second time, then app proceed running...

[Here's the source code.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4712155/prova%20self.dismissViewControllerAnimated%20locks%20app.zip)

How can I solve this issue?

NOTE FOR MODERATORS: It's not a duplicated of [UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: causes app to freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310999/uiviewcontroller-dismissviewcontrolleranimated-completion-causes-app-to-freeze), there trouble was caused from an external framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is, that you made a common mistake. You do NOT call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

That means, your "lock" of the app is just the  expected behavior of `didDeselect...`:

> This method is only called if there is an existing selection when the user tries to select a different row. The delegate is sent this method for the previously selected row. You can use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to disable the appearance of the cell highlight on touch-down.

Comment: So how can I get back to previous controller after a row selection?